# CodeCollaborator client fails to add files to review

Tags: perforce, p4v, code-collaborator

I am trying to submit a code review request using CodeCollaborator client v7.2.7237 (server version is same too) but fails with the following error call stack –

```
com.smartbear.ccollab.datamodel.DataModelException: org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: I/O error while communicating with HTTP server: Read timed out
at com.smartbear.ccollab.datamodel.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClientEngineImplementation$2.invoke(XmlRpcClientEngineImplementation.java:355)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.loadById(Unknown Source)
at com.smartbear.ccollab.datamodel.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClientEngineImplementation.loadById(XmlRpcClientEngineImplementation.java:441)
at com.smartbear.ccollab.datamodel.Engine$DataObjectCache.loadObjectById(Engine.java:6691)
at com.smartbear.ccollab.datamodel.Engine.loadById(Engine.java:537)
at com.smartbear.ccollab.datamodel.Engine.loadEngineObjectById(Engine.java:564)
at com.smartbear.ccollab.datamodel.Engine.versionCreate(Engine.java:5913)
at com.smartbear.ccollab.datamodel.Scm.uploadScmVersion(Scm.java:629)
at com.smartbear.ccollab.datamodel.Scm.uploadChangeset(Scm.java:448)
at com.smartbear.ccollab.datamodel.Scm.uploadChangeset(Scm.java:392)
at com.smartbear.ccollab.datamodel.Scm.uploadChangelist(Scm.java:291)
at com.smartbear.ccollab.client.commands.AbstractAddChangelistCommand.execute(AbstractAddChangelistCommand.java:139)
at com.smartbear.ccollab.client.commands.admin.review.AbstractReviewCommand.execute(AbstractReviewCommand.java:125)
at com.smartbear.ccollab.client.commands.Command.validateAndExecute(Command.java:345)
at com.smartbear.ccollab.client.commands.Command.validateAndExecute(Command.java:419)
at com.smartbear.collaborator.Collaborator.execute(Collaborator.java:160)
at com.smartbear.collaborator.jobs.AddToReviewJob.processChanges(AddToReviewJob.java:158)
at com.smartbear.collaborator.jobs.AddToReviewJob.run(AddToReviewJob.java:103)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: I/O error while communicating with HTTP server: Read timed out
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcCommonsTransport.writeRequest(XmlRpcCommonsTransport.java:252)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:151)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:115)
at com.smartbear.ccollab.datamodel.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClientFactory$XmlRpcCommonsTransport2.sendRequest(XmlRpcClientFactory.java:75)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:56)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:167)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:158)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:147)
at com.smartbear.ccollab.datamodel.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClientEngineImplementation$2.invoke(XmlRpcClientEngineImplementation.java:256)
... 18 more
```

I have no problems accessing Perforce or CodeCollaborator from the machine when I get this error. I tried to submit using CodeCollaborator plugin in P4V (P4V/NTX64/2019.1/1797168) but got the same error message. I tried JRE 1.6, 1.7 but got the same error.

When I login to my CodeCollaborator account, I see that review request is being created but it is failing to add the source files to the review. My colleagues with the same CodeCollaborator, P4 versions are successfully able to submit the review requests. Checked [this thread](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/Collaborator/Cannot-add-new-changelist/td-p/44282) on CodeCollaborator forum who had reported similar issue but there was no solution to try. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot ? Thanks.

Comment: have you figured it out? I have similar issue.

Comment: The issue happens only when I am on VPN. My company provides virtual office devices and when using those devices, I don't have to use VPN to access corporate resources. For now, I am using virtual office device support to submit my code reviews. We couldn't get support from Code Collaborator as we are using older version of server.

Comment: BTW, please post the solution if you figure out. Thanks.